# Why does "know" start with k but "gnostic" start with g?

Tags: etymology, orthography

It appears that *know* and *gnostic* share the same etymology (PIE *gnō*, apparently through Greek *gnōstikós*).  So how did they come to start with different letters?

Comment: You should find out ways to look up etymologies of words.  Only ask here if  you already looked, but did not find the answer.  Include your research in the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a comment @John Lawler wrote:

> An etymology is a path. *Know* and *gnostic* both come from [the same PIE root](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/roots.aspx?type=Indo-European&root=gn%C5%8D-), but that was 4000 years ago. 2500 years later or so, Germanic changed the G's to K's in most words, but Greek didn't. Later still, Greek *gnostic* got borrowed into English but it didn't replace *know*; it already had a different meaning because it took a different path. –
> John Lawler